# Lost dual-boot on Ubuntu 23.10 and update-grub seemed to find it but no changes to reboot, still just Ubuntu 23.10. What's missing?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 23.10

Input: `sudo update-grub`

Output:
`Sourcing file '/etc/default/grub'`
`Generating grub configuration file ...`
`Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-10-generic`
`Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-10-generic`
`Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic`
`Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic`
`Found memtest86+x64 image: /boot/memtest86+x64.bin`
`Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.`
`Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.`
`Found Windows Recovery Environment on /dev/sda1`
`Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda2`
`Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda3`
`Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...`
`done`

No changes on reboot.  Booted into **Ubuntu 23.10** only.  What am I missing?

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 was running Grub2.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to see the Grub menu by holding down the **Shift** key after powering on.

This enabled me to select the 'Windows 10' option and the 'check disk' I had called for ran.  Once this completed on restart Ubuntu 23.10 started and I was able to see all the files in the 'Windows 10' partition.